# Does editing columns, or adding new columns, in a document library actually consume version/size?

Tags: document-library, versioning

I have a document library (MOSS 2007) with Major versions, 5 versions, turned on.

I recently added a new column to the library - it happens to be a lookup from another List if that matters.

When I *Edit Properties* of an existing document, and add my new column data, I see a new Major Version created.

My Question: does this actually consume new **space** in the back end.  So if I have a 100KB Word Document uploaded, and now add my column, from the **Version History** page it looks like there are now two 100KB-consuming versions of the document.

Or is it smart enough to not duplicate the actual document, but merely the new column meta-data?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It will create a new copy and thus consume more space. Sharepoint versioning is dumb in that regard, it doesn't store a diff, it stores a new copy of the document.

Comment: Thankfully it's a bit better in 2013 with shredded storage!

Comment: Should be fun with 100mB+ cad files ^_^. PS: just to know, Eric, where did you find this info? MSDN or something more in-depth?

Comment: From first hand experience of using versioning in document libraries with metadata and looking at the version histores.